# Create custom post type with custom table

Tags: wordpress

I want to create custom post type with custom table, copy of (smae as like) wp_post and wp_postmeta. I tried this plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/pods/

But it is not exact what i want to do. Can you guys have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want a custom table? CPT use the wp_posts/wp_postmeta and differenciate themself from the regular post type with the "post_type" column.

Comment: @vard because clients wants to store it in different table.

Comment: May I ask why? Can't they query the wordpress tables with just the right WHERE clause? Because I don't think you will be able to use posts functionalities with custom tables - the table names are kind of hardcoded in wordpress core.

Comment: @vard Yes, i do other functionality hardcoded in wordpress core.

Comment: @vard I want this type of plugin if readymade plugin available then i just want to modify few of changes that i want.

Comment: You should really avoid that as you won't be able to update Wordpress anymore (and Wordpress have **a lot** of security issues that they fix really often). That said, I guess you could edit _wp-includes/query.php_ where WP_Query class is, and change `$wpdb->posts` occurences with your table name depending of `$q['post_type']`.

Comment: I think if i use separate plugin then not an issue on wordpress update.

Comment: @vard please see my above comment.